# Basic angularjs code not working properly

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Have installed the angularjs and Twitter.Bootstrap packages succesfully

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TodoApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <title>Amazing Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js:

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.test = "testing";
};
```

And, this is my list.html:

```
<h1>Test: {{test}}</h1>
```

This should work fine. However the index.html is not showing the content of list.html. I think the angularjs part is not working properly.

No idea about what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should move all your JS to the footer.

Comment: @Phill sorry couldnot get you...could you please elaborate

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/nKTsRfzR

Comment: @Phill : it still doesnot work!

Answer (score 2):

Once you have defined a module, you need to define your controllers for that module and not independently.

Thus, your controller should be rewritten as:

```
TodoApp.controller('ListCtrl', [ '$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.test = "Testing";
    }
]);
```

This should show the view in question.

Comment: thnx @callmekatootie however it still doesnot solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that if you check errors in console *(in Chrome or IE press F12)* you should see:

> ...Failed to instantiate module **TodoApp** due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: **`$routeProvider`**...

The reason for this expectation is that we ask IoC to inject `$routeProvider` while not correctly listing dependent modules. This is the above code:

```
var TodoApp = angular
  // here we say: we do not need any other module
  .module("TodoApp", [])
  // here we ask: inject $routeProvider from other module
  .config(function ($routeProvider)
```

So to make it runing we have to include the **module `'ngRoute'`**

```
var TodoApp = angular
  // here we say: we need these modules to make our module working properly 
  .module("TodoApp", [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  // now we can ask for the provider, 
  // using minification-safe syntax
  .config(
  [        '$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
      ...
  }]);
```

And also do not forget to also reference this module scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<!-- here we have to load this module -->
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you share the error from the console, please? I've tried localy and with these changes... it is really working. Do you have **angular-route** inside the scripts folder?. Summary: 1) if you will append the angular-route.js and 2) change the TodoApp as my snippet shows.. then if the `list.html` is in the same folder as index.thml ... it must work ;)

Comment: Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kHnXwlDcXmbm4poE8s1I - it is working, containing your code plus the above fixes

Answer (score 0):

What is your directory structure can you check if `list.html` is in the same directory as `index.html`, if not specify a relative path from the application root?

Comment: Your answer seems more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: This is a bit embaressing, but I posted as an answer coz, i didn't have enough reputation to comment :(

Comment: both list.html and index.html are indeed in the same location

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has posted a full correct answer to this question and it hasn't been closed yet, here is another answer.
This is your function:

```
var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.test = "testing";
};
```

This is a bare function, which isn't of much use. You need a controller so that Angular knows what to do with `{{ test }}`:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <h1>{{ test }}</h1>
</div>
```

If you insist on keeping the function as a separate variable, you could do so and still have a controller:

```
var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.test = "testing";
};

TodoApp.controller('someController', ListCtrl);
```

This also works.

Despite of this, your UI won't show, as there's an error in it:

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", [])
```

You're using `$routeProvider` and `.when()`,`.otherwise()`, for which you need `ngRoute` as a dependency:

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ['ngRoute'])
```

Your app should work after that.